# Principal Component Analysis in PHP

Tags: php, pca, computation

I'm looking for a class or a function, or just a piece of code that would do Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in PHP. I am interested in reducing dimensionality of some data.

I know that PHP is not the right language for heavy computation, so please don't suggest to use another language!

Comment: If you need to use PCA in a php program, can you farm it off to an external process and read the results from a pipe or file?

Comment: I'm one of the developers of a math and stats library for PHP called MathPHP (https://github.com/markrogoyski/math-php#statistics---multivariate---principal-component-analysis). This library can easily do PCA in PHP with no external dependencies.